# Merge other key values in multidimentional array if particular key values match

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, in which I have a few set of values. What I want to do here is to merge the key values "marks" and "course" if the values of the key "name" match. So far, I've done something like below to remove the duplicates:

```
$multi = array(
   array("name" => "Michael", "marks" => "25, 27, 34", "course" => "ABC"),
   array("name" => "Kumar", "marks" => "59, 71, 38", "course" => "DEF"),
   array("name" => "Peter", "marks" => "94, 43, 61", "course" => "JKL"),
   array("name" => "Kumar", "marks" => "83, 57, 73", "course" => "GHI"),
  );

$multiTemp = $multiNew = array();
foreach($multi as $key=>$val){
  if(array_key_exists($val['name'], $multiTemp) ) {
    continue;
  }
  $multiTemp[$val['name']] = 1;
  $multiNew[] = $val;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($multiNew);
echo "</pre>";
```

It just removes the duplicate values. Is therey any way to merge the other two values based on the condition I mentioned above the code? Just like the second and fourth array in the array `$multi` carry same values for `name`, so I want `marks` and `course` to be mereged into one. Thanks in advance for your help.

Current Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Michael
            [marks] => 25, 27, 34
            [course] => ABC
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kumar
            [marks] => 59, 71, 38
            [course] => DEF
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Peter
            [marks] => 94, 43, 61
            [course] => JKL
        )

)
```

Expected Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Michael
            [marks] => 25, 27, 34
            [course] => ABC
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kumar
            [marks] => 59, 71, 38, 83, 57, 73
            [course] => DEF, GHI
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Peter
            [marks] => 94, 43, 61
            [course] => JKL
        )

)
```

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: Hello there, RomanPerekhrest. Here it is: 


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Michael
            [marks] => 25, 27, 34
            [course] => ABC
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kumar
            [marks] => 59, 71, 38, 83, 57, 73
            [course] => DEF, GHI
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Peter
            [marks] => 94, 43, 61
            [course] => JKL
        )

)

Comment: Edited the question as well, to add the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_reduce()` + `arrray_values()` solution:

```
$multi = [
   ["name" => "Michael", "marks" => "25, 27, 34", "course" => "ABC"],
   ["name" => "Kumar", "marks" => "59, 71, 38", "course" => "DEF"],
   ["name" => "Peter", "marks" => "94, 43, 61", "course" => "JKL"],
   ["name" => "Kumar", "marks" => "83, 57, 73", "course" => "GHI"]
];

$result = array_values(array_reduce($multi, function($r, $a){
    $name = $a['name'];
    if (isset($r[$name])){
        $r[$name]['marks'] .= ', ' . $a['marks'];
        $r[$name]['course'] .= ', ' . $a['course'];
    } else {
        $r[$name] = $a;
    }
    return $r;
}, []));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Michael
            [marks] => 25, 27, 34
            [course] => ABC
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kumar
            [marks] => 59, 71, 38, 83, 57, 73
            [course] => DEF, GHI
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Peter
            [marks] => 94, 43, 61
            [course] => JKL
        )
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks so much Roman! I really appreciate your help :)